# Firebase app distribution not working for iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, firebase-app-distribution

I'm having a trouble with iOS part of **Firebase App Distribution** (android works without any issues).

My steps:

- I added **GoogleService-Info.plist** to Runner folder
- added "**firebase_analytics**: ^5.0.6" to project
- created .ipa file through Xcode->Product->Archive->Distribute App->AD Hoc
- added .ipa in firebase console and added testers
- testers succesfully **accepts** and **downloads** app

The issue comes up here: when testers (tested on two different devices) click on application white background shows up and disappears instantly (app is not launching/or launching and crashes...?)

Extra information:

- under settings -> general-> profile only **Firebase app
  distribution** that is listed (no    trace of installed app)
- first when adding testers and sending invatatioin , they have to
  login through google account    when going trough the process - in
  both testers cases theirs apple-ID and google account are    not the
  same
- iOS application works without any issues when running on device connected to computer

any suggestions would be very appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible you're using an outdated or expired provisioning profile or certificate? You might also want to reach out to support@fabric.io - they can provide more support and dig into your device logs there!

Comment: hi kevin, no both are valid until december. Fabric?(I thought firebase took totally over from fabric-interesting... )- ty will contact them:)

Comment: Firebase support is the main avenue for this, but the Fabric support team is still there up until Fabric's deprecation!

Comment: ok, ty for information:)

Comment: Hi @pb4now did you find any solution for this issue?

Comment: @GabriellaAngelova nowdays (diffrent project then I mentioned in question) it just works- but I remember that I had to run "flutter build --release" to make proejct in question work, hope it helps.

Comment: Hm, okay, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

This issue doesn't seem to be relevant anymore per checking the comments. I've also tried replicating the behavior, but everything went well on my end. Given that the issue isn't directly caused by Flutter SDK, if other folks has similar issues, I suggest reaching out to Firebase Support https://firebase.google.com/support